# Merge array in java

Tags: java

I need merge array by id of object. I have two arrays (local and global) of my class:

```
public class Info {
    private int id;// never change
    private String msg;
    private boolean isFavor;// presents only in local array
// constructor,getters, setters etc 
}
```

Rules of merging:

1. If object is not present into global array we don't merge it;
2. Take msg only from global object ;
3. If object is present into global array we add  (merge) it;
4. Variable "isFavor" take from local object ;
5. Arrays are not sorted;

Example:

```
local arayList = {Info(1,"msg1",false),Info(2,"msgTwo",false),Info(3,"msg3",true), Info(4,"msg4",true)};

global arayList = {Info(1,"msg1",false),Info(2,"msg2",false),Info(3,"msg3",false),Info(5,"msg5",false)}

result arayList = {Info(1,"msg1",false),Info(2,"msg2",false),Info(3,"msg3",true),Info(5,"msg5",false)}
```

Comment: Your rules can be simplified to "update `isFavor` field from corresponding object in local array". Should resulting array be a new entity or updating the `global` is enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did something like this which I think does what you want. Basically, what I do is the following. I add all the global values to the map and in the next iteration of the local values, I check if the id exists, I change the `isFavor`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    List<Info> local = new ArrayList<>();
    local.add(new Info(1,"msg1",false));
    local.add(new Info(2,"msgTwo",false));
    local.add(new Info(3,"msg3",true));
    local.add(new Info(4,"msg4",true));


    List<Info> global = new ArrayList<>();
    global.add(new Info(1,"msg1",false));
    global.add(new Info(2,"msg2",false));
    global.add(new Info(3,"msg3",false));
    global.add(new Info(4,"msg5",true));

    Map<Integer, Info> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (Info info : global) {
        if (!map.containsKey(info.id)) {
            map.put(info.id, info);
        }
    }

    for (Info info : local) {
        if (map.containsKey(info.id)){
            map.get(info.id).isFavor = info.isFavor;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(map.values());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Info [] merge(Info [] localArray, Info [] globalArray) {

    List<Info> resultList = new ArrayList();
    for(Info infoGlobal : globalArray) {
        Info infoLocal = findInfo(infoGlobal.getId(), localArray);
        if( infoLocal != null )
            infoGlobal.setFavor(infoLocal.isFavor());
        resultList.add(infoGlobal);
    }

    return resultList.toArray();
}

private Info findInfo(int id, Info [] infoArray) {

    for(Info info : infoArray)
        if(info.getId == id)
            return info ;

   return null ;
}
```